# Parse csv columns to separate arrays with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a csv file with 16 columns to 16 separate arrays. I need each cell to be another object in the array. So the values in column 1 becomes arr1, column 2 becomes arr2, etc. This is the code I have so far:

```
file = "FS_Email_Test.csv"

arr1 = []
arr2 = []
arr3 = []
list =CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ";", :return_headers => false) do |row|
        arr1 << row[0].to_i
        arr2 << row[1].to_i
        arr3 << row[2].to_s
      end
puts arr1
```

This code correctly parses column1 into arr1, but it returns 0 values for arr2 and arr3. I need it to work for each column. Ideas/thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you please give us some example content of the CSV file?

Comment: Going to need to see some example input to get an idea of what's going on here, preferably actual input.

Comment: Sure. Email, ID Number, email@email.com, 2, test@gmail.com, 1. The content is pretty irrelevant as it will change from time to time. I just need everything that is in the first column, Column A to become one big array. Then I need everything in the second column, Column B to become a separate array. So on and so forth for 16 columns.

Comment: Problem solved- I just needed to remove the .to_i and .to_s. I will answer the question when time permits.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. There was an issue with the .to_i and .to_s on the end of the arrays. I took that piece off and the code works just fine. Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
file = "FS_Email_Test.csv"

arr1 = []
arr2 = []
arr3 = []
list =CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => ";", :return_headers => false) do |row|
        arr1 << row[0]
        arr2 << row[1]
        arr3 << row[2]
      end
puts arr1
```